# How to extract JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to extract the value from the event key (delivered) using PHP. I thought the follow would work below but I'm getting no results. I know this is probably a simple thing to do and probably looking too far into it.

**How I am trying to extract the value**

```
$status = json_decode($status, true);
echo $status[1]['event'];
```

**Here is my JSON file**

```
{ 
   "events":[ 
      { 
         "email":"email@gmail.com",
         "date":"2020-02-17T22:16:58.000+01:00",
         "subject":"PHPMailer SMTP test",
         "messageId":"<hdskjfjsdhfsjdkfdksh>",
         "event":"delivered",
         "tag":"",
         "from":"test@gmail.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `echo $status['events'][0]['event'];`

Comment: You should use print_r($status) to look at the structure of your array. That should help make it clear how to access the nested elements.

Comment: It is already clear. An invalid json results in null, when passed to json_encode

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is that your JSON file is wrong formatted. It should be:

```
{
 "events": [
  {
   "email": "email@gmail.com",
   "date": "2020-02-17T22:16:58.000+01:00",
   "subject": "PHPMailer SMTP test",
   "messageId": "74483437597589347843758934759",
   "event": "delivered",
   "tag": "",
   "from": "test@gmail.com"
  }
 ]
}
```

Second, `$status[1]['event']` is also wrong. You should use `$status['events']`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did update my JSON post. I apologize... I was using a JSON viewer extension installed in Chrome web browser - so the format was correct. I just made the mistake and didn't show you it that way. Sorry!

Comment: I tired to use $status['events'] and echo it out but it's still showing nothing on the page. Any idea?

Comment: The presented JSON is equal to the OPs JSON.

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out. So I am parsing a json response from CURL...

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

**I changed this**

```
$status = json_decode($status, true);
echo $status['events'][0]['event'];
```

**to**

```
$status = json_decode($response, true);
echo $status['events'][0]['event'];
```

I totally missed that mistake. Thanks to everyone who reach out!

Comment: `$status[1]['event']` is wrong, it's `$status['events'][0]['event']`. The first thing in the JSON `object` you show us in the question is the `events` `array`, which contains `event` `objects`.

Comment: The code you show results in `Notice: Undefined index 1 in $status` - you should enable `error_reporting(E_ALL)` level including notices while developing.